# Why do Attribute members need to be public?

Tags: c#, attributes, visibility

## Problem

Attempting to use the attribute

```
internal class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    internal string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

like this

```
[Foo(Bar = "hello world")]
public class MyOtherClass { }
```

(in the same assembly) yields

> error CS0617: 'Bar' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static.

However, I can perfectly fine access `Bar` from *"in code"*, e.g.

```
FooAttribute attribute = new FooAttribute { Bar = "hello world" };
```

---

## Solution

However, if I change the attribute to

```
internal class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    ^^^^^^
}
```

I can use it as intended.
Note that I only had to mark the property `public` - not the attribute itself as well. This "fixed" the issue, despite *effectively* not changing the visibility of `Bar`.

---

**Why are attributes "special" in this case - why does the compiler require their fields to be public?**

<sub>The [documentation on the error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0617) doesn't mention **why** they need to be public either.</sub>

Comment: There's no significant benefit to marking the property as `internal` if you've already marked the class `internal`.

Comment: So let's say you make the attribute public, that means another assembly wouldn't be able to set the property on it. That's pretty nasty.

Comment: Not sure why you need this, I'd probably try to refactor that functionality. But you could probably get around it using an internal constructor instead `internal FooAttribute(string bar) { Bar = bar; }`. Don't forget to also have a public constructor.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow You've already handled that by making the attribute itself internal. I'm not 100% sure why C# won't let you do this, but it wouldn't make a difference anyway. Just mark the property public.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow That's why I made a comment and not an answer. I was implying that the property could be made `public` with no impact since the class itself is `internal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are attributes "special" in this case

You're identifying the wrong part of it as special. The special thing about attributes is that there is a syntax for a combination of construction and setting of public properties for an object associated with fields, classes, methods, etc.

In other words the special thing about attributes is that they are attributes!

Indeed, it's not even the attribute that is special; as you said yourself you can create an instance of the same class with an initialiser the same as you can any other. It's the attribute syntax that's special.

It has to allow the ability to call a public constructor (or construction would never be possible) and it has to allow the setting of public properties (or properties would never be set). It's noteworthy also that this predates the introduction of initialiser syntax into C#, so once upon a time it was only possible to combine construction and immediate setting of public properties in one syntactic unit in the case of attributes.

So considered thus, there's no point comparing with how things work with initialisers as they didn't exist when the relevant design decisions were being made.

So, let's just consider `[Foo(Bar = "hello world")]` on its own, and think about when `Bar` should be settable in this way.

The reasons to allow it when `Bar` is public should be pretty obvious.
The reasons to not allow it when `Bar` is private should also be pretty obvious.
When its internal there are two reasonable choices; to not allow or to allow when the attribute exists within the given assembly.

So the question then is how useful is it to have an attribute which is public (if it was internal itself we could achieve the same thing with all-public properties) and can hence be used in other assemblies but which has internal properties that can only be set in attribute use from the same assembly. If this was super-useful then it would be worth the extra work and complexity of allowing it. If it was not super-useful then better for both theory (the spec) and practice (the compiler) to not allow it.

It would seem it was not considered super-useful.